# x86 assembly programmer converting to MIPS, what should I know?

Tags: x86, mips, assembly

I have programmed in x86 architecture for my previous school, and in a new class that I am taking that requires knowledge of MIPS. What are some of the main differences in concept and architectures between the two worlds? thanks

Comment: If you have no clue then you really ought to take a MIPS class first.  SO is not a substitute for education, we can't cram a semester into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been awhile since I looked at MIPS ASM, but from what I recall...

Depending on how well you already know x86 assembly language, I don't think MIPS ASM will be too difficult to pick up. Obviously, being a very pure RISC instruction set, it's much simpler than x86. You have some data movement instructions (load/store), some arithmetic instructions (add, subtract, multiply, bit shifting and masking), and branching (un/conditional jump). There are not too many embellishments on those themes.

You may feel a bit spoiled, in fact, when you try MIPS and see the incredible number of general purpose registers at your disposal. You know how x86 tends to be a struggle with 7-8 general purpose regs (depending on whether you count ESP)? You have 32 GP regs in MIPS.

One thing you have to get used to is the pipelining, or rather the implications of pipelining. If one instruction executes an addition, and the result is supposed to go into register r5, the sum may will not actually be available by the time the next instruction executes. It may need another cycle or 2 (don't remember the specifics) before r5 holds the sum. So you have to plan for that in your code. Another implication is that a branch instruction does not branch right away (again, due to pipelining, it may take a cycle or 2). Thus, you need to make sure the instruction that happens to be after the branch does not mess up the program state in a weird way (put a NO-OP after the branch if in doubt).

I have always found that the best way to learn any ASM is to disassemble a program into ASM and start looking up the instructions. To that end, download and install a MIPS toolchain ([here's a great place to get up to date, cross-compiling toolchains for numerous architectures, including MIPS](http://autobuilder.yoctoproject.org/pub/nightly/CURRENT/toolchain/)). Use it to compile a "Hello World" C program, as well as a few basic math formulas, and then run the MIPS version of 'objdump -d' on the executable. Study the output, starting from the main() function. Understand how the C math maps onto MIPS ASM.

Good luck! It's not exactly trivial, but if you already have x86 proficiency, I think you can probably learn other ASM sets without having to take a semester-long course in the topic.